# C++ variadic templates to cascade inheritance. how to upcast?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Given a cascaded inheritance hierarchy in C++:

```
struct MyBaseClass
{
protected:
   void f();
};

template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
struct MyClass<Fn, Args...> : MyClass<Args...>
{
...//from here can I access MyBaseClass::f() ?
}; 
template <typename Fn>
struct MyClass<Fn> : MyBaseClass{...};
```

As indicated in the above comment line, I want to call a protected method from MyBaseClass from the scope of MyClass.
How is that possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative solution to Maxim's is fully qualifying the function name with the class's name ([demo](http://ideone.com/7Bq2Q8)):

```
MyBaseClass::f();
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to call a protected method from MyBaseClass from the scope of MyClass.

There are a few ways you can invoke a *template dependent function* of a base class from a derived class:

```
this->f();         // Call f of this class, or any base class.
this->MyClass::f() // Call MyClass::f of MyClass base sub-object of this class only.
MyClass::f()       // Call MyClass::f either of MyClass base sub-object or of any unrelated MyClass.
```

See [Dependent names](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) for more detail.